# Jenkins pipeline throws reporting:org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

> Jenkins pipeline throws
>   reporting:org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException:
>   Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.util.XmlSlurper parseText
>   java.lang.String

Here is the code:

```
def testsuites = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
```

Also I could not see this method in ScriptApproval. How can we whitelist this method manually or any other solution to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested your use case with Jenkins **2.60.3** and after running a script that uses `new XmlSlurper().parseText(someXml)` I get expected exception:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method groovy.util.XmlSlurper parseText java.lang.String
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:175)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:9)
```

And I see in `/scriptApproval` I can approve it:

[image]

You can always try adding this approval manually. In Jenkins home directory you can find `scriptApproval.xml` file. Add:

```
<string>method groovy.util.XmlSlurper parseText java.lang.String</string>
```

inside `<approvedSignatures>` tag and restart Jenkins. It will cause the same effect as approving this signature via Jenkins UI.